# Can a v1 PF reciever power an XL motor and servo?

Tags: power-functions, motor, electronics

I have a v1 PF receiver but don't want to pay $35 for a v2 receiver and I was wondering if a v1 receiver can power a single XL/L motor and a servo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried connecting an XL motor and a servo motor to a v1 receiver and yes, it works just fine. ( I knew it would anyhow :) )

The only thing that might be a problem is that some V2 receivers are not labelled 'V2' but are unlabelled like V1 receivers are. But I'm sure that I have still done this before V2 receivers even came out and it worked.

If you want the motors to be independent you must put them on separate channels of the receiver and have both the receiver channel selector and the remote control channel selectors to the correct channels in which the motors are connector.

V2 has slightly more IR range over v1 however I have heard that v1 has a higher output to the motors.

If you want the motors synchronized for whatever reason then you can put them on the same channel of the receiver.